# add items to combobox from xmlnodelist

Tags: c#, xml

How can I add items to dynamically created combobox from an xmlnodelist.

```
<Root>
  <Class Name="ECMInstruction" Style="Top">
    <Entity Id="1" Name="DocumentInformation" />
    <Entity Id="2" Name="CustomerInformation" />
    <Property Id="1" Name="DocumentTitle">
    </Property>
    <Property Id="2" Name="DateCreated">
      <Lists>
        <ListName>ws_Users</ListName>
        <ListName>dfdfdfd</ListName>
      </Lists>
    </Property>
    <Property Id="3" Name="Deadline">
    </Property>
  </Class>
  <Class Name="AlphaCertificationsIndividual" Style="Top">
    <Entity Id="1" Name="DocumentInformation" />
    <Property Id="1" Name="DocumentTitle">
    </Property>
    <Property Id="2" Name="DateCreated">
      <Lists>
        <ListName>ws_Users</ListName>
        <ListName>dfdfdfd</ListName>
      </Lists>
    </Property>
    <Property Id="3" Name="Deadline">
    </Property>
  </Class>
</Root>
```

Am iterating through an xml file to get all the attributes and create their labels and textboxes accordingly. When it reaches the attribute entity I want to put all the values from the id attribute from "entities" XmlNodeList.

```
    XmlNodeList attributes = document.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//Class[@Name='" + classname + "']/Property[@Id='" + id + "']/attribute::*");
    XmlNodeList entities = document.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//Class[@Name='" + classname + "']/Entity");


    table1.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = attributes[x].Name, AutoSize = true });
    table1.Controls.Add(new ComboBox() { Name = attributes[x].Name, SelectedText = attributes[x].Value,Items = { entities[x].Value }, AutoSize = true });
```

The compiler gives me null reference

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incomplete but I think you wrote a

```
foreach (XmlNode x in attributes) { ... }
```

or similar. This will not include entity elements.

You should try:

```
List<string> items = new List<string>();
foreach (XmlNode y in x.ParentNode.SelectNodes("Entity"))
{
    items.Add(y.Value);
}
table1.Controls.Add(new ComboBox() { Name = attributes[x].Name, SelectedText = attributes[x].Value,Items = items, AutoSize = true });
```

Or if you prefer and familiar with Linq, you can write:

```
x.ParentNode.SelectNodes("Entity").Cast<XmlNode>().AsQueryable().Select(n => n.Value);
```

Comment: compiler gives me Property or indexer 'Items' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

Comment: This should work:
ComboBox cb = new ComboBox() { Name = attributes[x].Name, SelectedText = attributes[x].Value, AutoSize = true };
foreach (XmlNode y in x.ParentNode.SelectNodes("Entity"))
{
    cb.Items.Add(y.Value);
}
table1.Controls.Add(cb);